# How left join works with sqlx

Tags: mysql, go, sqlx

I'm trying to inner join two tables `person` and `profile` with a simple query which seems to work fine with mysql but not with sqlx. 
Here's my go code:

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type Person struct {
    Id      int64   `db:"id"`
    Name    string  `db:"name"`
    Email   string  `db:"email"`
}

type Profile struct {
    Id          int64   `db:"id"`
    Face        string  `db:"face"`
    Hair        string  `db:"hair"`
    Person
}

func main() {
    DB, err := sqlx.Connect("mysql", "root:hackinitiator@/dusk")
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("sucess!!")
    } 
    var q []Profile
    DB.Select(&q, "select person.id, person.name, person.email, profile.id, profile.face, profile.hair from profile left join person on person.id = profile.person_id")
    fmt.Println(q)
}
```

The mysql query produces the following output:

```
+------+------+---------+----+----------+--------+
| id   | name | email   | id | face     | hair   |
+------+------+---------+----+----------+--------+
|    1 | yoda | nomail  |  1 | round    | brown  |
|    5 | han  | nomail1 |  3 | circle   | red    |
|    6 | yun  | nomail2 |  4 | triangle | yellow |
|    7 | chi  | nomail3 |  5 | square   | green  |
+------+------+---------+----+----------+--------+
```

which is perfectly fine but my go program is not responding as expected. The struct is unable to capture the profile id(empty in output) and person id is replaced with profile id. Below is the output(formatted):

```
[
{0 round brown {1 yoda nomail}} 
{0 circle red {3 han nomail1}} 
{0 triangle yellow {4 yun nomail2}} 
{0 square green {5 chi nomail3}}
]
```

I'm unable to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: You cannot have multiple columns with the same name in the result set, it's just `mysql` cli feature that it handles it

Comment: Okay, I don't know how to do it. I tried using `profile.id as profile_id` instead of `profile.id` but it didn't work. Can you provide me a little more help?

Comment: I googled for "go sqlx join select" and this is the first result: https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/757-how-to-join-two-tables-with-jmoiron-sqlx

Comment: There is absolutely nothing unique about left join (or any join) in sqlx. sqlx just handles the rows returned by your database--the logic behind that query is 100% irrelevant to sqlx.

Answer (score 1):

Following the snippet provided by [@zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) I made a few changes which allowed me to run the program without errors and without renaming db tags.
First, I added the below code in profile struct to let the query identify person struct

```
Person `db:"person"`
```

Following this I changed my SQL query string to the below code

```
DB.Select(&q, `select person.id "person.id", person.name "person.name", person.email "person.email", profile.* from profile left join person on person.id = profile.person_id`)
```

to avoid duplicate column names as pointed out by [@zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `db` name in `person` struct like below i'm describing because there would be two column with same name i.e. `id` so it scan only last one id which is in your `profile` table and not scan of `person` table, so follow the struct as mentioned below.

```
type Person struct {
    Id      int64   `db:"pId"`
    Name    string  `db:"name"`
    Email   string  `db:"email"`
}
```

And then write your query with `as` for `person.id` like

```
DB.Select(&q, "select (person.id) as pId, person.name, person.email, profile.id, profile.face, profile.hair from profile left join person on person.id = profile.person_id")
```

Comment: I can't change the db name as I'm working with already existing database. I find the snippet provided by @zerkms closest to my query and it did in fact solved my problem.

Comment: you don't need to change anything inside database you have to just change struct `Person` like  here I'm talking about `Id      int64   ``db:"pId"` ,  this `db` actually you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to returning two `id` columns from the result but storing the result in a struct with same field name id in both structs, whose instance you are passing to DB.Select. Try to capture single id column and pass it to struct.

Pass multiple columns but different columns name which you can use as an alias. The column alias name will be the field in the Person struct in which you are scanning the data as:

```
type Person struct {
    PersonId    int64   `db:"personId"`
    Name        string  `db:"name"`
    Email       string  `db:"email"`
}

var q []Profile
DB.Select(&q, "select person.id as personId, person.name, person.email, profile.id, profile.face, profile.hair from profile left join person on person.id = profile.person_id")
fmt.Println(q)
```